# gsutil rsync from google cloud storage to s3 hangs on large file

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am experiencing a hang on a larger file (560MB) when attempting to backup my google cloud storage bucket to aws s3 bucket using the following command:

```
gsutil -m rsync -rd gs://<MyGoogleBucket>/ s3://<MyS3Bucket>/
```

I know the connection is good because it copies about 150 smaller files (9MB) before it hangs on the larger file with no apparent error message, just a hung progress bar in the shell.

When I hit ctrl-C to exit the program i notice several messages that say:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Here is my version of gsutil:

```
gsutil version: 4.38
checksum: 58d3e78c61e7e0e80813a6ebc26085f6 (OK)
boto version: 2.49.0
python version: 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
OS: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): /etc/boto.cfg, /home/USER/.boto
gsutil path: /home/USER/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

I have tried doing this in my cloud shell as well as on a Google Compute VM

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for this issue?  Thanks in advance

-Nathan

Comment: Create a folder with only that file. Then try again. Do not press CTRL-C. Wait until the command finishes or reports an error. The fact that 150 files were successful means nothing in debugging your problem except to verify that you can connect and copy a small file. If you can reproduce this on Compute Engine, then turn on gcloud debugging and review the output. A bug with gcloud on Compute Engine will get attention.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is yet to be known if there is really an error, using `-m` option for parallel processing on `gsutil rsync` can affect the behavior for sizable synchronizations between storage especially networks. This can also be found on the reference [1] which mentioned:

> m (multi-threading) option, gsutil can consume a significant amount of network bandwidth. In some cases this can cause problems, for example if you start a large rsync operation over a network link that's also used by a number of other important jobs.

If the issue continues, you can either test the `gsutil rsync` without the `-m` option or utilize the alternatives mentioned in the same reference [1].

[1] [Throttling gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Throttlinggsutil)

Answer (score 0):

For large objects in GCS use gsutil -o option. From the docs

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Answer (score 0):

I have started using rclone and it has simplified the process and allowed the copy to complete.  You can find info on using this tool here:  https://rclone.org/docs/

-n

Answer (score 0):

> If the issue continues, you can either test the gsutil rsync without the -m option or utilize the alternatives mentioned in the same reference [1].

I think the developers have recently fixed the issue as the `-m` is no longer necessary and these don't happen anymore:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: This didn't help and it still fails randomly.